# how to execute multi requete pdo mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i don't know how execute multi requete sql

```
   <?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_SESSION['pseudo']) && !empty($_SESSION['pseudo']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

        $id     = trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']));
        $pseudo = trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['pseudo']));
        $stmt->$connect->prepare('SELECT id,pseudo,jeton FROM users  WHERE id=:id AND pseudo=:pseudo');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':id' => $id,
            ':pseudo' => $pseudo
        ));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($_SESSION['pseudo'] == $row['pseudo'] && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $row['id']) {



            // Files Image profil
            $avatarName    = $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['name'];
            $avatarTmp     = $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['tmp_name'];
            $avatarSize    = $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['size'];
            $avatarType    = $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['type'];
            $extension     = array(
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'png'
            );
            $avatarExplode = explode('.', $avatarName);
            $avatarEnd     = end($avatarExplode);
            $avatarLower   = strtolower($avatarEnd);



            $saveIdUser    = trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']));
            $saveIdUserNew = filter_var($saveIdUser, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $avatar        = rand(0, 100000) . '_' . date('Y-m-d H-i-s') . '_' . $saveIdUserNew;

            if (isset($avatarName) && !empty($avatarName)) {

                if ($avatarSize < 8000000) {
                    if (in_array($avatarLower, $extension)) {
                        if (isset($avatarTmp) && !empty($avatarTmp)) {


                            $image = getimagesize($avatarTmp);
                            if ($image['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
                                $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg($avatarTmp);

                            } elseif ($image['mime'] === 'image/png') {
                                $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng($avatarTmp);
                            } else {
                                $imageSrc = false;

                            }
                            // modifier size image
                            if ($imageSrc !== false) {
                                $imageWidth  = 60;
                                $imageHeight = 60;

                                if ($image[0] >= $imageWidth && $image[1] >= $imageHeight) {
                                    $imageFinale = $imageSrc;
                                } else {
                                    $newWidth[0]  = $imageWidth;
                                    $newHeight[1] = $imageHeight;
                                    $imageFinale  = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth[0], $newHeight[1]);
                                    imagecopyresampled($imageFinale, $imageSrc, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth[0], $newHeight[1], $image[0], $image[1]);
                                }


                                $target = imagejpeg($imageFinale, 'upload/avatarPost/' . $avatar . '.jpg');

                                move_uploaded_file($avatarTmp, $target);
                            } // ! == false 

                        }


                    }

                }

            }

            $stmt = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO users(avatarcouverture) VALUES(:avatarne) ');

            $stmt->execute(array(
                ":avatarne" => $avatar
            ));

            //header('Location: profil.php');
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What I know there is not possible to do multi query in PDO.

Comment: The initial `$stmt->$connect->prepare(...` should be `$stmt = $connect->prepare( ...`

Comment: Do you know how to execute one "requete"? Is there anything you have tried? Does it work from other SQL clients? Could you be so nice to format your code (provided it's necessary at all) so that people can read it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was the initial prepared statement assignment

```
$stmt->$connect->prepare('SELECT id,pseudo,jeton FROM users  WHERE id=:id AND pseudo=:pseudo');
```

it should be perhaps more like this.

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT id, pseudo, jeton FROM users WHERE id=:id AND pseudo=:pseudo');
```

---

The final sql query surely should only be run if there is a successfully added avatar? Reorganised a little whilst looking for issues - hope it helps.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {
    if( !empty( $_SESSION['pseudo'] ) && !empty( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ) {

        $id = trim( htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) );
        $pseudo = trim( htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['pseudo'] ) );
        /*
            Assign the prepared statement as a variable
        */
        $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT id, pseudo, jeton FROM users WHERE id=:id AND pseudo=:pseudo');
        if( !$stmt )exit('Failed to prepare sql');
        $stmt->execute( array(
                        ':id'       => $id,
                        ':pseudo'   => $pseudo
                    )
                );
        $row=$stmt->fetch();

        if( $_SESSION['pseudo'] == $row['pseudo'] && $_SESSION['user_id'] == $row['id'] ) {

            $avatarName     =   $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['name'];
            $avatarTmp      =   $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['tmp_name'];
            $avatarSize     =   $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['size'];
            $avatarType     =   $_FILES['avatarCouverture']['type'];

            $extension      =   array('jpg','jpeg','png');
            $avatarLower    =   strtolower( pathinfo($avatarName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

            $saveIdUser  = trim( htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) );
            $saveIdUserNew = filter_var( $saveIdUser, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ); 
            $avatar = rand(0,100000).'_'.date('Y-m-d H-i-s').'_'.$saveIdUserNew;

            if( !empty( $avatarName ) ) {
                if( $avatarSize < 8000000 ) {
                    if( in_array( $avatarLower, $extension ) ){
                        if( !empty( $avatarTmp ) ) {

                            $image = getimagesize( $avatarTmp );

                            if( $image['mime'] === 'image/jpeg' ) {
                                $imageSrc = imagecreatefromjpeg( $avatarTmp );
                            } elseif( $image['mime']==='image/png' ) {
                                $imageSrc = imagecreatefrompng( $avatarTmp );
                            } else {
                                $imageSrc = false;
                            }

                            // modifier size image
                            if( $imageSrc !== false ) {

                                $imageWidth = 60;
                                $imageHeight = 60;

                                if( $image[0]>= $imageWidth && $image[1]>= $imageHeight ) {
                                    $imageFinale = $imageSrc ;  
                                } else {
                                    $newWidth[0]  = $imageWidth;
                                    $newHeight[1] = $imageHeight;
                                    $imageFinale = imagecreatetruecolor( $newWidth[0], $newHeight[1] );

                                    imagecopyresampled( $imageFinale, $imageSrc, 0,0,0,0, $newWidth[0], $newHeight[1], $image[0], $image[1] );
                                }

                                $target = imagejpeg( $imageFinale,'upload/avatarPost/'.$avatar.'.jpg' );

                                move_uploaded_file( $avatarTmp ,$target );


                                $stmt=$connect->prepare('INSERT INTO users( avatarcouverture ) VALUES( :avatarne )');
                                if( !$stmt )exit('Failed to prepare sql');
                                $stmt->execute( array( ":avatarne"=> $avatar ) );                               

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            //header('Location: profil.php');
        }
    }
}
```